# Media server RAID difficulties (on FreeNAS)

Tags: freebsd, raid, freenas

<sup>*Disclaimer: I've never used FreeNAS or any type of RAID before, so this is a first.*</sup>

I've decided to build a media server in my new apartment. I'm going to be going with a total 10TB of space (6x2TB discs in a RAID 5, unless I get recommendations to use another RAID). I've also decided to go with FreeNAS on a recommendation of a friend. Here are some of my issues regarding this setup:

- Seeing as buying 6 2TB drives is quite a bit of money, I was wondering how hard it would be to say start with 3 discs, wait until they are full, then add another disc to the array. Is this even possible with RAID5?
- My media is currently on 3 1TB drives (non-RAIDed). How straightforward is it to use FreeNAS to transfer files over? I assume I would have to set up my RAID first, then transfer the old files into it one hard drive at a time, right?

Also, how would the above differ if I was using RAIDZ (I'm not quite sure how easy it is to set up)

Comment: Adding disks to a RAID5 array is not a simple operation, it requires moving a lot of data around. Linux's mdraid supports this (the raid driver moves the data while the system is live), I don't know about FreeBSD.

Comment: If I decide to go the Linux way and use `mdraid`, does it require having a second set of discs? Or can it work with only the existing array and the new disc coming in?

Comment: Linux can add a disk at a time to a RAID5 or RAID6 array.

Comment: The question about RAIDZ is a FAQ: http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/FAQs You _can_ add disks to non-raid volumes, though.